# Generator vs Suspend

Tags: c++, kotlin, coroutine

In C++23, with the generator introduced, C++ starts to support coroutine. So a function can be paused and resumed. However, Kotlin does not have a concept of the generator, instead, it has conceptions like Coroutine Scoep/Context, Dispatchers, and suspends. Does the C++ and Kotlin Coroutine achieve the same goal using different syntax? Or are there some fundamental differences between those coroutine implementations?

Comment: Isn't Kotlin's Sequence (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html) a generator by another name?

Comment: You can use coroutines to make generators, yes.

Comment: C++20 supported coroutines as a language feature, but didn't provide any in `std`. `std::generator` is one kind of coroutine